# Создаю бота, который в Telegram генерирует QR-код. Мой код не работает

Tags: python, telebot, qrcode

```py
import pyqrcode
import telebot
import png


bot = telebot.TeleBot('')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_message(message):
    def make_qrcode(url):
        qrcode = pyqrcode.create(url)
        qrcode.png('QR CODE.png', scale=6)
        with open('QR CODE.png', made='rb') as file:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=file)
    if message.text.find == "/make" != 1:
        get_url = message.text.replace("/make ", "")
        make_qrcode(url=get_url)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Чтобы получить ваш QR CODE, попробуйте написать /make [ссылка]")


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Желательно предоставить желаемое и текущее поведение, и в чём ошибка

Comment: Сейчас когда я пишу /make и ссылку , он мне не выдает qr код , по коду думаю понятно что я хочу код в виде картинки . Строчку та где with open  он подчеркивает , но я не понимаю зачем

Comment: @Александр у функции `open` нет аргумента `made`, попробуйте `mode` либо же вообще без него, просто `rb`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Я это убрал уже , все равно ничего не выдает

Comment: @Александр а ошибка какая при запуске?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея мне показалась забавной, так что вот мои варианты фикса.

1. Вариант, QR - код сохраняется в файл и отправляется:

```
import pyqrcode
import telebot
import png

bot = telebot.TeleBot('!!!-ТОКЕН-!!!')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_message(message):
    def make_qrcode(url):
        qrcode = pyqrcode.create(url)
        with open('QR_CODE.png', 'wb') as file:
            qrcode.png(file, scale=6)
        with open('QR_CODE.png', 'rb') as file:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=file)

    if message.text.startswith("/make "):
        get_url = message.text.replace("/make ", "")
        make_qrcode(url=get_url)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Чтобы получить ваш QR CODE, попробуйте написать /make [ссылка]")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

2. Вариант, через буфер:

```
import pyqrcode
import telebot
import io

bot = telebot.TeleBot('!!!-ТОКЕН-!!!')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_message(message):
    def make_qrcode(url):
        qrcode = pyqrcode.create(url)
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        qrcode.png(buffer, scale=6)
        buffer.seek(0)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=buffer, caption='Ваш QR код')

    if message.text.startswith("/make "):
        get_url = message.text.replace("/make ", "")
        make_qrcode(url=get_url)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Чтобы получить ваш QR CODE, попробуйте написать /make [ссылка]")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала создаем объект QR

```
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,                        
                   error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
                   box_size=10,
                   border=2,
                   )
```

Передаем в него данные, которые надо "зашифровать"

```
qr.add_data(data)
```

Создаем маску. В примере используется SquareGradiantColorMask квадратный цветовой градиент. Передаем в него цвета: цвет фона, цвет начала градиента из центра и цвет конца градиента по краям.

```
color_mask = SquareGradiantColorMask(back_color=(12, 12, 12),
                                     center_color=(255, 254, 114),
                                     edge_color=(85, 50, 43))
```

Создаем изображение используя модуль Pillow, добавляем в центр QR кода изображение параметром embeded_image_path

```
img = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage,
                    embeded_image_path=f"{base_dir}/src/embedded.png",
                    module_drawer=RoundedModuleDrawer(
                                               radius_ratio=0.5),
                                               color_mask=color_mask)
```

И сохраняем готовое изображение

```
path = Path(f"{base_dir}/img")

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)

img.save(Path(f"{path}/{img_name}.png"))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]